# pdo extensions not found

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

I am getting `Caught exception: could not find driver` in my

```
function connect_to_server()
    {
        $serverName = DB_HOST;
        $this->_connection = new PDO("odbc:Driver={SQL Server};Server=$serverName,1433; Database=".DB_NAME.";",DB_USER,DB_PASS);
        // $this->_connection = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=192.168.1.97;Server=$serverName,1433; Database=".DB_NAME.";",DB_USER,DB_PASS);

        if(!$this->_connection)
        {
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }
        else
        {
            return $this->_connection;
        }
    }
```

When I have it inside try catch like

```
try {
            $this->_con = $this->connect_to_server() . "\n";
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
        }
```

So I wanted to install the driver from [here](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-the-memcached-php-extension-on-centos-7/) i am in step `yum -y install php-pecl-memcache` when i run in command i get

```
Error: php71w-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

So i tried to find solution for this and found [this](https://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/303795-php-issues-with-mysqli-extension-and-pdo-pdo-mysql-extensions/)
 So i run `yum install php70w-mysqli` but it returned same same error.

> What is the correct way to install these drivers.

I can run this in my local because I have these:

```
extension=php_bz2.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
extension=php_gettext.dll
;extension=php_gmp.dll
;extension=php_intl.dll
;extension=php_imap.dll
;extension=php_interbase.dll
;extension=php_ldap.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_exif.dll      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
;extension=php_oci8_12c.dll  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=php_openssl.dll
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_shmop.dll
```

But in my server I dont have these in php.ini.

I only have this

```
; If you wish to have an extension loaded automatically, use the following
; syntax:
;
;   extension=modulename.extension
;
; For example, on Windows:
;
;   extension=msql.dll
;
; ... or under UNIX:
;
;   extension=msql.so
;
; ... or with a path:
;
;   extension=/path/to/extension/msql.so
;
; If you only provide the name of the extension, PHP will look for it in its
; default extension directory.
```

**UPDATE**

tried using `yum -y install php_odbc`

But got

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Repository packages-microsoft-com-prod is listed more than once in the configuration
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.pregi.net
 * epel: mirror.pregi.net
 * extras: mirror.pregi.net
 * updates: mirror.pregi.net
 * webtatic: sp.repo.webtatic.com
No package php_odbc available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Wher i run: ***php -i | grep PDO***

I get:

```
PDO
PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers => mysql, sqlite
PDO Driver for MySQL => enabled
PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x => enabled
```

Comment: Did you try restarting apache or php-fpm?

Comment: yes using  `systemctl restart httpd.service` in localhost i use windows OS in server it is centOS7. in `php -i | grep PDO` it should have `odbc` right?? @LawrenceCherone

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,the extension directive blocks in your environment is not work.The reason is your system can not find the extension files. In the php.ini doc,it has an example:

```
For example, on Windows:
extension=msql.dll

under UNIX:
extension=msql.so
```

That  indicates the difference configurations between Windows and Unix(Linux).In your system, the php.ini on extension block should like this:

[extension_dir](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQ9Y1.png)

[extesion_file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptG2b.png)

In a word,

in `Windows`,the extensions files is in `/ext/`,and tail with `dll`,

in `Linux`, the extensions files is in `prefix/lib/php/`, and tail with `so`.

Comment: when i run `yum -y install php-odbc-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64.rpm` I get  `Error: php71w-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest` ***how do i fix this error? it keeps popping up***

Comment: as its literal meaning said,when you install `php-odbc-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64.rpm`, the `rpm` package encounter a dependency error,and you can try `yum -y install install php-odbc-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64.rpm --skip-broken ` .

Comment: i said `Packages skipped because of dependency problems:
    libzip-0.10.1-8.el7.x86_64 from base
    php-common-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64 from base
    php-odbc-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64 from /php-odbc-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64
    php-pdo-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64 from base
`i guess it is not installed because it was skipped the odbc

Comment: yes it there was no error but there was no installation also

Comment: what's your php version?

Comment: running `php -v` gets me `PHP 7.1.8 (cli) (built: Aug  9 2017 19:19:49) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
`

Comment: try `yum -y install php70w-odbc-7.0.22-2.w7.x86_64.rpm`,which can be found in https://pkgs.org/download/php70w-odbc

Comment: i run `wget https://pkgs.org/download/php70w-odbc/php70w-odbc-7.0.22-2.w7.x86_64.rpm` but it doesnot complete the download only 0s

Comment: got it from `wget http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/el7/x86_64/RPMS/php70w-odbc-7.0.22-2.w7.x86_64.rpm` but running `yum -y install php70w-odbc-7.0.22-2.w7.x86_64.rpm` same error

Comment: @Martin I have found an alternative package which matchs your php version in https://centos.pkgs.org/7/remi-x86_64/php71-php-odbc-7.1.8-1.el7.remi.x86_64.rpm.html. If not, my opinion is that you can try  tarball  installing PHP.The reason is that the php tarball `/ext` include the  corresponding `pdo_odbc` extension with current PHP version.

Comment: `[root@www ~]# yum --enablerepo=remi install php71-php-odbc
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Repository packages-microsoft-com-prod is listed more than once in the configuration
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.pregi.net
 * epel: mirror.pregi.net
 * extras: mirror.pregi.net
 * remi: repo1.sea.innoscale.net
 * remi-safe: repo1.sea.innoscale.net
 * updates: mirror.pregi.net
Package php71-php-odbc-7.1.9-1.el7.remi.x86_64 already installed and latest version
` ***it is installed but why it is not in php -m list?***